how to wire a SPST 2-pin on-off latching switch as a power on-off for raspberry pi zero
I'd like to set up a switch (on the outside of the case/enclosure) to power up/power down (halt state) a RP zero.
I have a 2-pin SPST on-off latching switch (specifically, this one: https://thepihut.com/products/spst-on-off-latching-miniature-toggle-switch), but all the examples I've seen of "power buttons" use momentary switches. Also, some of those examples use resistors and some don't (which I gather is to do with which pins you connect to, although I'm not really clear on that).
Can anyone help me understand how to wire up the latching switch and whether I need to use resistors, or perhaps point me in the direction of some easy-to-understand documentation?

Why don't you ACTUALLY follow one of the unreferenced examples?

This question is similar to: Raspberry Pi 3 model B "dtoverlay=gpio-shutdown". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Milliways Because, as I mentioned, the examples use a momentary switch rather than a latched switch and I wanted to check if that made a difference. And secondly, that other question is related in that it's to do with the shutdown process, but I'm specifically asking about wiring with regards to the 2-pin switch rather than the process itself.

The main problem with a toggle switch is contact bounce; also just connecting to an unspecified GPIO without any code won't shut the Pi down. The answer is also ambiguous; if you use to cut 5V power sooner or later you will end up with a corrupted OS.

You can see your switch as a 3-pin SPDT switch with one pin missing. Your common pin (the one in the center of your component) is permanently connected. Your common pin will stay unconnected if the switch is on the left. If you switch to the right, your common and right pins will be shorted.
For your application, I see two possibilities :

You could connect your common pin your 5V power supply and the right pin to the 5V of your Rpi Zero.
Your Raspberry will be either powered up or unpowered and you don't need any resistor. Your Pi will be turned off even if the firmware inside crashes.

You could connect your common pin to a 3V3 and the right pin to a GPIO, using a pull-down circuit for your GPIO if needed (if you are not using internal pull-up/pull-down in your device). Like this, you can programmatically halt your Rpi when the GPIO goes high. Note that in this case your Pi will be turned off only if your program is still running.


Here is a quick illustration of the circuitry


Thanks @Bibibou. So it's not necessary to use a resistor on the GPIO pin then? I've seen some examples where they use a 220k ohm on the GPIO as well as the one on GND.

@Lenny It's up to you, inside the RPI there are internal pull up/down that you can use and it will do the job. Putting your own pulldown resistor will still be the safest option in my opinion. you can see a discussion about that topic here
